# I am getting an error while fetching data from firestore(firebase). I am using react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase

this is the error I am getting

ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string
(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `FetchData`.

I created a collection and named it baghdad in Firebase.
Everything looks fine but I am getting this error.
Here are my codes

```
----------
FetchData.js 
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain:"-.m",
  projectId: "-",
  storageBucket: "-..",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

import { Component } from "react";

import { ScrollView, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List } from "react-native-paper";
export { auth, db };
class FetchData extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.docs = firebase.firestore().collection("baghdad");
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      baghdad: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.docs.onSnapshot(this.getStudentsData);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  getStudentsData = (querySnapshot) => {
    const baghdad = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
      const { name, business_status } = res.data();
      baghdad.push({
        key: res.place_id,
        name,
        business_status,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      baghdad,
      isLoading: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.wrapper}>
        {this.state.baghdad.map((res, i) => {
          return (
            <List key={i} bottomDivider>
              <List.Content>
                <List.Title>{res.name}</List.Title>
                <List.Subtitle>{res.business_status}</List.Subtitle>
              </List.Content>
              <List.Chevron color="black" />
            </List>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingBottom: 22,
  },
  loader: {
    position: "absolute",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

export default FetchData;

---------

App.js

import React from "react";
import FetchData from "./src/FetchData";
export default function App() {
  return <FetchData />;
}
```

Thanks for any help and support

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing two things:
First, I was using List incorrectly. and secondly, I installed a react-native-elements package using yarn.

in your terminal:
1- write
yarn add react-native-elements

2- import ListItem in FetchData

3- in FetchData.js
replace List with ListItem